# CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing - PHP, Angular

Tags: php, angularjs

Currently developing an API in PHP which has the following headers

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
```

which works when called from Postman and from an Ionic application.

However when calling it from a web application on localhost using angular I get an error with

> Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Despite the header being present and other application applications being able to call it.

Comment: Is the webapplication on a different port ?

Comment: I don't think that should matter considering I have header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *') ?

Comment: try  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST");

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your config.xml file:

```
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-intent href="*"/>
```